# Изменить <tr> таблицы JQuery?

Tags: jquery

html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id = "mainForm">
 <header id ="mainFoter" align = "center"><h1>Аптека<h1></header> 
  <table id = "mainTable">
    <caption><strong>АНТИБИОТИКИ</strong></caption>

<tr>
  <td>
    <strong>НАЗВАНИЕ ЛЕКАРСТВА</strong>
  </td>
  <td>
    <strong>КАРТИНКА</strong>
  </td>
</tr>

  <tr>
   <td>
   Оспамокс
   </td>
   <td>
   <img height = "150px" width = "180px" src = "../img/1.jpg"> 
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>
   Азитромицин
   </td>
   <td>
   <img height = "150px" width = "180px" src = "../img/2.jpg"> 
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
   <td>
   Амоксиклав
   </td>
   <td>
   <img height = "150px" width = "180px" src = "../img/3.jpg"> 
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>
   Аугументин
   </td>
   <td>
   <img height = "150px" width = "180px" src = "../img/4.jpg"> 
   </td>
  </tr>

</table>
     <button id = "button1">Первая кнопка</button>
       <button id = "button2">Вторая кнопка</button>
 </form>
      <script src="../js/index.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

js:

```
               var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
               var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

               button1.addEventListener('click', Function1);
               button2.addEventListener('click', Function2);

          function Function1(event){
             event.preventDefault();

             $('tr:even').addClass('even');
           }
```

CSS:

```
         .even {
            color: red; 
            font-size: 4px;
           }
```

При нажатии на кнопку изменить цвет текста четных строк jquery.Не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery и jQuery-UI это разные библиотеки.

Вам нужен jQuery (либо оба и jQuery и jQuery-UI), а вы подключили jQuery-UI.

jQuery-UI добавляет в jQuery ращличные UI элементы (модальные окна, аккордион ...), при этом он не может заменить сам jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Когда интерпретатор JS попадает на ошибку в коде, код после ошибки не выполняется. В данном случае ошибка будет в том, что вы ссылаетесь на функцию `Function2`, которой не существует. Если бы вы проверили код отладчиком, вы увидели бы ошибки, исправление которых решит проблемы.

Comment: Проблема была не в этом. Она у меня реализована, но я специально убрал её и никакой ошибки не произошло, остальные функции выполняются прекрасно. Отладчиком? В Sublime?

Comment: Специально загуглил. Бред:"В данном случае ошибка будет в том, что вы ссылаетесь на функцию Function2, которой не существует. " Никакой ошибки не будет, для кнопки, к примеру, после нажатия выполнится действие по умолчанию.

Comment: @bsuart2017 отладчиком браузера. Но, в прочем, догадка Arnial оказалась верной.